# Flutter ListView.builder remove extra spacing

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a list of cards inside a ListView.builder on each card i'm giving  transform:Matrix4.translationValues(x,Y,z) i have extra spacing from the last item to bottom of page is there a way to remove the last spacing? and i can't remove the transform:Matrix4.translationValues() it's necessary in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible because to remove the space. but what you can do is also matrix transform whatever is below your `ListView.builder` up to fill the gap.